# Reshaping 2 numpy dimensions into one with zipping?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pytorch

I tried searching for this question but I couldn't find anything relevant.

The quickest way to describe the problem is with a simple example:
lets say I have a 2D numpy arrayl like this:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3],
[10, 11, 12, 13],
[20, 21, 22, 23]]
```

So it has the shape [3,6]
I want to reshape it into a 1D array that looks like this:

```
[0, 10 ,20 ,1 ,11 ,21 ,2 ,12 ,22 ,3 ,13 ,23 ]
```

Unlike the array we get with reshape:

```
[ 0,  1,  2,  3, 10, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22, 23]
```

Now, to the actual problem I have...
I actually have a 3D array and I want to reshape it into 2D array, and I want to do so with the method described above.
And another example would be:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([[[0,1,2],[10,11,12],[20,21,22]],
[[100,101,102],[110,111,112],[120,121,122]],
 [[200,201,202],[210,211,212],[220,221,222]]])
a.shape
a.reshape(3,9)
OUTPUT: array([[  0,   1,   2,  10,  11,  12,  20,  21,  22],
       [100, 101, 102, 110, 111, 112, 120, 121, 122],
       [200, 201, 202, 210, 211, 212, 220, 221, 222]])
```

And again, I want my output to look like this instead:

```
[[  0,  10,  20,   1,  11,  21,   2,  12,  22],
 [100, 110, 120, 101, 111, ..................],
 [...........................................]]
```

EDIT: just for the sake of people who google this problem, I add some search terms that some people might search for:

Interweave dimensions numpy array

Zip dimensions numpy array

Numpy reshape ordered dimensions

Tensor reshape dimensions timesteps

Comment: The standard solution when reshaping doesn't order the elements in the desired way, is to `transpose` or `swapaxes`, either before or after the reshape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to swap the last two axes with `np.swapaxes` or `np.transpose` and then reshape.

For `2D` input case, it would be -

```
a.swapaxes(-2,-1).ravel()
```

For `3D` input case, only the reshape part changes -

```
a.swapaxes(-2,-1).reshape(a.shape[0],-1)
```

Generic way : To make it generic that would cover all n-dim array cases -

```
a.swapaxes(-2,-1).reshape(a.shape[:-2] + (-1,)).squeeze()
```

**Sample runs**

2D case :

```
In [186]: a
Out[186]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [10, 11, 12, 13],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])

In [187]: a.swapaxes(-2,-1).reshape(a.shape[:-2] + (-1,)).squeeze()
Out[187]: array([ 0, 10, 20,  1, 11, 21,  2, 12, 22,  3, 13, 23])
```

3D case :

```
In [189]: a
Out[189]: 
array([[[  0,   1,   2],
        [ 10,  11,  12],
        [ 20,  21,  22]],

       [[100, 101, 102],
        [110, 111, 112],
        [120, 121, 122]],

       [[200, 201, 202],
        [210, 211, 212],
        [220, 221, 222]]])

In [190]: a.swapaxes(-2,-1).reshape(a.shape[:-2] + (-1,)).squeeze()
Out[190]: 
array([[  0,  10,  20,   1,  11,  21,   2,  12,  22],
       [100, 110, 120, 101, 111, 121, 102, 112, 122],
       [200, 210, 220, 201, 211, 221, 202, 212, 222]])
```

---

Runtime test -

```
In [14]: a = np.random.rand(3,3,3)

# @mahdi n75's soln
In [15]: %timeit np.reshape(a,(3,9), order='F')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.22 µs per loop

In [16]: %timeit a.swapaxes(-2,-1).reshape(a.shape[0],-1)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 µs per loop

In [20]: a = np.random.rand(30,30,30)

# @mahdi n75's soln
In [21]: %timeit np.reshape(a,(30,900), order='F')
10000 loops, best of 3: 28.4 µs per loop

In [22]: %timeit a.swapaxes(-2,-1).reshape(a.shape[0],-1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 18.9 µs per loop

In [17]: a = np.random.rand(300,300,300)

# @mahdi n75's soln
In [18]: %timeit np.reshape(a,(300,90000), order='F')
1 loop, best of 3: 333 ms per loop

In [19]: %timeit a.swapaxes(-2,-1).reshape(a.shape[0],-1)
10 loops, best of 3: 52.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, very elaborate examples and explanation. I will try to use both, this and the other answer, and see which one will work faster. I hope this thread will help people like me who couldn't find a relevant thread when searching for this problem.

Comment: @artembus Added timings.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple answer here on the documentation of [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

`np.reshape(a,(3,9), order='F')`

Comment: Original! - Though @Divakar's is still more general.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use [np.ravel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) with `order='F'`.

```
In [35]: arr
Out[35]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [10, 11, 12, 13],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])

In [36]: np.ravel(arr, order='F')
Out[36]: array([ 0, 10, 20,  1, 11, 21,  2, 12, 22,  3, 13, 23])
```

Please note that unlike in `np.reshape()`, you don't have to specify any shape information here.